# How to only highlight function definitions and not function calls in python VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

[image: Highlighted code]

In this image the function definition "planetorbit" is highlighted, however, so are "speed", "resizemode" and "shapesize".

Is there a way to only have "planetorbit" highlighted?

I have tried using `"scope": "entity.name.function"` in textMate but this highlights them both.

My settings for color alterations are:

```json
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled" : true,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "keywords": "#FF8000",
        "comments": "#DD0000",
        "strings": "#02ff02dc",
        "variables": "#FFFFFF",
        "functions": "#FFFFFF",
        "numbers": "#FFFFFF",
        "textMateRules": [
            {"scope": "variable.parameter",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF"}},
            {"scope": "meta",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF"}},
            {"scope": "support.function",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#5e5eff"}},
            {"scope": "keyword.operator",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF"}},
            {"scope": "punctuation.separator",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF"}},
            {"scope": "entity.name.function",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#5E5EFF",}},
            {"scope": "entity.name.function-call",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF",}},
        ]
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#7E7E7E",
        "editor.background": "#002240",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#FFFFFF",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#FFFFFF",
        "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#FFFFFF",
        
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Abyss",
```

Comment: if they have different TextMate Scopes you can give them different colors

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `"scope": "entity.name.function-call"` in Seting to `scope": "entity.name.function.member"` to achieve the effect you want.

```json
            {"scope": "entity.name.function.member",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF",}},
```

[image]

*Or add it behind `entity.name.function-call`.*

```json
            {"scope": "entity.name.function-call,entity.name.function.member",
            "settings": {"foreground": "#FFFFFF",}},
```

*It should be noted that such a custom grammar highlights may always be unsatisfactory, because many Scope is repeated.You may have modified a scope to get a certain effect you want, but at the same time, the effect of changing another type makes you dislike.*